# Prove the convergence of the LASSO model in the presence of limited eigenvalues

Tags: st.statistics, machine-learning

I am researching the properties of the Lasso model $\hat \beta:= \operatorname{argmin} \{\|Y-X\beta\|_2^2/n+\lambda\|\beta\|_1\}$, specifically its convergence when the data satisfies restricted eigenvalue conditions. I would like to find a proof of convergence for the model under such conditions. Specifically, consider the following problem:

We can get faster rate when $X$ satisfies restricted eigenvalue conditions.

If $\gamma=\inf _{v \in \mathcal{C}} \frac{v^{\prime} \frac{X^{\prime} X}{n} v}{\|v\|^2}>0$, with $\mathcal{C}=\left\{v:\left\|v_{\bar {A^*}}\right\|_1 \leq 3\left\|v_{A^*}\right\|_1\right\}$ and $A^*=\operatorname{supp}\left(\theta^*\right)$.
Set $\lambda=2 \sigma \sqrt{\frac{2 \ln (2 d / \delta)}{n}}$, then, with probability at least $1-\delta$,
$$
\left\|\hat{\beta}_{\mathrm{L}}-\beta^*\right\|_2 \leq \frac{6}{\gamma} \sqrt{2 \ln (2 d / \delta)} \sigma \sqrt{\left|A^*\right| / n} .
$$
I am seeking a detailed explanation of the proof steps, derivations involved, and the necessary assumptions. Additionally, if there are any relevant references or existing theoretical results supporting the proof, please provide the relevant information.